# Not HDMI output to a smart TV on laptop HP Pavilion dv7

Tags: windows-7, laptop, hdmi, hp-pavilion

I have a Laptop - HP pavilion dv7 complete model (dv7 - 6c95dx) with Windows 7. I formatted the laptop repeatedly.

I'm sure the problem is not in either the HDMI cable or the smart TV, because I have tried in other laptops and it works CORRECTLY.

Before typing here I read several post Stand HP but none solve my problem.

Note: I have noticed that when connecting the HDMI cable to the smart tv's on the screen "No Signal" and when they disconnect "No conctado wire".

***UPDATE:***
I installed Ubuntu on a flash memory and tried the HDMI to rule it was Windows. I do not think that is the motherboard for I have reviewed several post HP and many people have the same problem.

Comment: Are you sure the TV is on the correct HDMI input? Are you going into your laptop display settings and choosing to duplicate or extend your screen?

Comment: Yes I did that and restarted the laptop several times. Another thing is that I tried with two other laptops and just put the HDMI cable works for me without having to modify other settings.

Comment: It's possible that the HDMI output on your motherboard could be bad. Can you try hooking up the VGA port to your TV and see if that works?

Comment: Just to ensure, have you tried Windows+P and used options listed in selection screen?

Comment: Yes, I did that. My laptop has keyboard key for that.